# How to transport fresh ravioli to office potluck?

Tags: pasta, fresh, food-transport, ravioli

I made some fresh ravioli to take into an office potluck. I only have access to a microwave at work to reheat the food. I also don't want my ravioli to stick to each other once cooked. I'm thinking of boiling the ravioli at home, immersing them in tomato sauce in a microwaveable container, and then reheating the entire container in order to serve. Any other ideas/suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like you've already figured out the most practical way to do it. Can you boil water in the microwave to cook the ravioli there? Is bringing it in a crock pot an option? Is there any particular disadvantage to doing it exactly as you described?

Comment: I ended up using a crock pot yesterday, cooking the ravioli in the morning and dumping the ravioli and sauce in the crock pot together. This turned into ravioli lasagna as everything stuck together and didn't reheat well on the warm setting I used. I won't be using the crock pot option again.

Comment: Thank you for replying back about what happened! — I'm sure it was no less delicious, @Eleanor, if perhaps not the texture you hoped for. Maybe next time, it would be better not to mix your sauce with the ravioli until ready to serve... dress the ravioli with a few drops of olive oil to keep it from sticking together... etc.? — Pat's answer sounds like a good idea too.

Comment: I make and freeze ravioli, and cook them frozen, so transport is no problem: just put them in an ice box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take the question to mean how you can best preserve the fresh-made texture with microwaving?

I would make, cool and store ravioli in single layers on parchment/waxpaper in a container for transport. Separately,  the sauce transported in largest microve-safe container that will fit in office micowave. 
Heat sauce to boiling then gently add in ravioli and continue to reheat on defrost if stirring would damage ravioli, or higher setting if you  can stir halfway through time.